# Linux: Give Write permission to another user

Tags: linux

I have a "user1" main user. its home directory is /home/user1/
I want to give write permission to my another user "user2" to inside a specific folder like "/home/user1/www/download"
How I can do it?

Comment: try to google "linux folder permission"

Comment: I believe that this question is off topic and should be directed to the Unix&Linux SE site.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+w /home/user1/www/download
```